# No se ejecuta de forma correcta mi código

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, function

Estoy realizando un ejercicio, pero este no me da el resultado de ganaste o de seguir participando, la oración de el ejercicio es la siguiente:

Escribí la función `esPremioMayor` la cual recibiendo dos arrays, el primero con los números sorteados y el segundo con los números que jugaste. La función debe devolver el texto "Ganaste" si y solo si los 6 números jugados son iguales a los números sorteados, no importa el orden en el que hayan salido, de lo contrario devolverá la frase "Seguí participando", y la frase que me como error es la siguiente:

La función `esPremioMayor` ejecutada con los siguientes arrays: `numerosSorteados` [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ] y `numerosJugados` [ 4 , 12 , 13 , 17 , 33 , 40 ] debería darnos como resultado la frase 'Ganaste'.

La función `esPremioMayor` ejecutada con los siguientes arrays: `numerosSorteados` [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ] y `numerosJugados` [ 7, 19 , 22 , 36 , 41 , 42 ] debería darnos como resultado la frase 'Seguí participando'.

```js
let numerosSorteados = [12, 4, 40, 33, 13, 17];
let numerosJugados = [4, 12, 13, 17, 33, 40];

function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados) {
  if (numerosSorteados == numerosJugados) {
    return "Ganaste";
  } else {
    return "Segui participando"

  }
}
console.log(esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados));
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Supongo que es javascript? y luego de eso, para comparar 2 arrays, no alcanza con decir que sus referencias son iguales. Tenes que escribir una funcion que compare los valores de uno y otro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola estas comparando el referencias y no los elementos dentro del arreglo, puedes hacer algo asi:

```js
let numerosSorteados = [12, 4, 40, 33, 13, 17];
let numerosJugados = [4, 12, 13, 17, 33, 40];

function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados) {
  let ganador = true;
  
  for (let step = 0; step < numerosSorteados.length; step++) {
    if(!numerosSorteados.includes(numerosJugados[step]))
      { ganador = false; break; } 
  }
  
  if (ganador) {
    return "Ganaste";
  } else {
    return "Segui participando"

  }
}
console.log(esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre encontrar una solución:

```
 function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados)
{
   var cont = 0;

   numerosSorteados.sort();
   numerosJugados.sort();

   for(var i = 0; i<=5;i++)
   {
      if(numerosJugados[i] == numerosSorteados[i])
      {
          cont++;
      }
   }

   if(cont == 6)
   {
      return "Ganaste";
   }
   else
   {
       return "Seguí participando";
   }
}
```